# Make generic property in non generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have one abstract generic class like this:

```
public abstract class ServicoAbstrato<TEntity, TId>
  where TEntity : EntidadeBasica<TId>
  where TId : IEquatable<TId>
{
    protected IDao<TEntity, TId> dao; ...
}

public abstract class EntidadeBasica<TId>
  where TId : IEquatable<TId>
{ ... }
```

and I want to have a property of this generic class in another class like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets .Field)]
public class ServicesAttribute : HandlerAttribute
{
    public ServicoAbstrato<EntidadeBasica<Type>, Type> servico { get; set; }

    public override ICallHandler CreateHandler(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        return new ServicesHandler(servico);
    }
}
```

but it gives me the following error:

> The type 'System.Type' cannot be used as type parameter 'TId' in the generic type or method 'Servico.ServicoAbstrato'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.Type' to 'System.IEquatable'

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: pretty straightforward, you have a contstraint `TId : IEquatable<TId>`, and `Type` is not `IEquatable<Type>`

Comment: Just like in the marked duplicate, the type you are trying to use as the generic type parameter does not implement the interface your generic declaration requires the type parameter to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Type` in a place where `TId` is defined. And `TId` as a restriction in the `where`-clause so that it must be of type `IEquatable<TId>`.

`Type` (at least the `Type` you used) is a Microsoft class and does not fulfill that condition.

If you have a class `Equatable<T>` somewhere which implements the interface `IEquatable<T>`, you could use

```
public ServicoAbstrato<EntidadeBasica<Type>, Equatable<Type>> servico { get; set; }
```